# Laptop screen flickers when using battery power

Tags: laptop, display, battery

1. When my laptop is NOT plugged into a power outlet, and is above 25% screen brightness the screen will occasionally flicker.
2. To be more specific, at 0% and 25% screen brightness there is never flickering.  At 50% and 75% screen brightness there is flickering that occurs only on specific websites (screen color arrangements).  At 100% screen brightness there is always flickering.
3. When my laptop is plugged into the wall there is never screen flickering (at any brightness).
4. I believe this is not a software issue as this problem exists on a clean copy of Windows 7, Windows 10, and Linux (Ubuntu).

Does anyone have a clue as to what is wrong with my laptop?  I think it may be the battery, but it also could be my laptop screen.

Comment: Perhaps the refresh rate is lowered while on battery mode and that seems to be the flickering? Mine was lowered to 40 Hz and it was kind of flickering.

Comment: Could you create an image (e.g., via MS Paint) that makes your screen mostly dark or mostly white? Perhaps your screen uses auto-brightness on battery power and bright websites cause the brightness to go down -- and then rise again as the ambient light gets darker, and round and round we go. Or make sure your room is bright to keep brightness up if this is the case.

Comment: My refresh rate is 60Hz when on battery power and plugged into an outlet.  Also, my screen does not use auto-brightness it is set manually.  Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Brightness flickering is sometimes caused by the `Enable adaptive brightness` knob in `powercfg /q`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I was able to fix my problem with money. I now own a new laptop.